# Regex list files, when windows cannot create that file that already exists

Tags: python, regex

Basically, I want to list only those files that windows will not create.
How do I list 4.txt and 4a.txt instead ...   `s == s` being true?

```
myList = '''
4.txt
4a.txt
spam
'''
myregex = 'a' 
s = re.sub(myregex,'',myList)

if s == s:    
    print "got it!"  # prints 'got it'
    print s == s     # prints 'true'
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. It seems you have misunderstood quite some things. Why do you put `s == s` there, which is always evaluated to `True`?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import re
myList = '''
4.txt
4a.txt
spam
'''.split()
myList
reList = [
    '4\w?\.txt', #4 followed by 0 or 1 alphanumeric then .txt
    '4.*\.txt',   #4 followed by anything and then .txt
    '\d\w?\.txt', #a digit, then 0 or 1 alphanumeric then .txt
    ]

for name in myList:
    for regex in reList:
        if re.match(regex, name):
            print ("%s matches %s" % (name, regex))
        else:
            print ("%s does not match %s" % (name, regex))
```

Output:

> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > ```
> > > 4.txt matches 4\w?\.txt
> > > 4.txt matches 4.*\.txt
> > > 4.txt matches \d\w?\.txt
> > > 4a.txt matches 4\w?\.txt
> > > 4a.txt matches 4.*\.txt
> > > 4a.txt matches \d\w?\.txt
> > > spam does not match 4\w?\.txt
> > > spam does not match 4.*\.txt
> > > spam does not match \d\w?\.txt
> > > ```

Comment: You should tag this post as python.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regex for that.
Just check whether the file exists or not with `os.path.exists`

```
import os
lst = [your_fileNames....]

for arch in lst:
    if not os.path.exists(arch):
        print arch
```